# Query returns no results

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]I have a small issue where in i am unable to understand why nothing is getting printed  `system.debug(SelectedAccountIDs);` here.

Here i am taking some selected accounts into `forselectedaccounts` and based on `forselectedaccounts.MDM_Account_ID__c` condition, i am fetching id from account and adding it into a list `SelectedAccountIDs`.

`MDM_Account_ID__c`  is nothing but a account field. But i dont know either query is wrong or what the query is returning 0 rows.

`SelectedAccounts` contains some account fields which also have `MDM_Account_ID__c`.

```
public void UpdateSeattleClubAccount(){
    List<Account> SelectedAccounts=new List<Account>();
    List<Account> SelectedAccountIDs=new List<Account>();
    List<Account> UpdateAccount=new List<Account>();
    Set<id> accids=new Set<id>();

    for(GetCheckedAccounts GCA :Gcalist){
        if(GCA.Selected==true)
            SelectedAccounts.add(GCA.Acc);
    }

    for(Account forselectedaccounts : SelectedAccounts){
        system.debug(forselectedaccounts.MDM_Account_ID__c);
        SelectedAccountIDs.add([Select id from Account where MDM_Account_ID__c like :forselectedaccounts.MDM_Account_ID__c]); 
    }
    system.debug(SelectedAccountIDs);
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is having Accounts ` SelectedAccounts.add(GCA.Acc);` this line adds selected accounts to SelectedAccounts List

Comment: system.debug(forselectedaccounts.MDM_Account_ID__c); and even this line is printing MDM id

Comment: Rather than doing `DM_Account_ID__c like :forselectedaccounts.MDM_Account_ID__c`, try doing `DM_Account_ID__c = :forselectedaccounts.MDM_Account_ID__c`. If you're getting an Id, the Id will either be right or wrong and you wouldn't want to get similar ones.

Comment: Tried that also but no hits  :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build SOQL with Like operator then build the queries like this:

```
SELECT id from Account FROM Account 
WHERE MDM_Account_ID__c Like '%NM0%' 
OR MDM_Account_ID__c Like '%NM1%'
```

For example:

```
List<String> AccountIds = new List<String>();
AccountIds.add('0019000001nNLGEAA4');
AccountIds.add('0019000001l0iK9AAI');

String str = 'Name LIKE %' +  String.join(AccountIds, '% OR Name Like %') + '%';

System.debug('str=' + str);
```

> USER_DEBUG [7]|DEBUG|str=Name LIKE %0019000001nNLGEAA4% OR Name Like %0019000001l0iK9AAI%

So, in your code, it could be like this:

```
List<String> mdmAccountIds = new List<String>();
for(Account forselectedaccounts : SelectedAccounts){
    system.debug(forselectedaccounts.MDM_Account_ID__c);
    mdmAccountIds.add(forselectedaccounts.MDM_Account_ID__c);   
}

if(mdmAccountIds.size()>0)
{
    String str = 'MDM_Account_ID__c LIKE %' +  String.join(mdmAccountIds, '% OR MDM_Account_ID__c Like %') + '%';
    System.debug('str=' + str);
    String queryString = 'SELECT id from Account where ' + str; 

    SelectedAccountIDs = Database.query(queryString); 

    system.debug(SelectedAccountIDs);
}
```